# PHP preg_match() PCRE logic issue?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

Consider the following:

```
$lat = '89° 5'; // works
if(preg_match('/^(([0-8]\d|\d)°?(\s?([0-5]\d|\d))?)(N|S)?$/', $lat, $la)){
  $ck = 'DD° MM format --> ';
}
else{
  $test = 'invalid $lat format';
}
if(isset($ck)){
  $test = $ck.$la[0];
}
echo $test;
```

When `$lat = '89°5'` everything works fine too. What I'm trying to understand is why `$lat = '89 5'` fails? Maybe my brain isn't working, but it seems that last one should not be an invalid format because of `°?`. Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: Works for me https://regex101.com/r/kG4kH6/1

Comment: I can't get that last one to pass on localhost. I'm using XAMPP with PHP 7.0.4 . Anyone have the same issue? I still don't get it.

Comment: `@Machavity` it works in your example but not on my Server. Why would this be?

Comment: Can anyone tell me if they have the same issue?

Comment: What happens if you add the `/u` modifier?

Comment: I get the invalid format error on a php 5.6 install on debian. I will play with this...

Comment: Thank you. It seems it should pass, logically.

Comment: 3v4l.org works for all versions of PHP: https://3v4l.org/2aL3N

Comment: I was able to get it to pass both using: `/(*UTF8)^(([0-8]\d|\d)°?(\s?([0-5]\d|\d))?)(N|S)?$/` @PHPglue, can you confirm?

Comment: `@Mike` Output is `invalid $lat format` when `$lat = '89 5';`. Please read my entire question.

Comment: `@user866762` those both worked, but why should I have to do this? My File Encoding is UTF-8, if that helps.

Comment: `/(*UTF8)` is probably what I will use, so I don't run in to other problems, but I think PHP should use your File Encoding by default. Let's call this a bug.

Comment: What are valid strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/(*UTF8)^(([0-8]\d|\d)°?(\s?([0-5]\d|\d))?)(N|S)?$/`

From http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt:

> In  order  process  UTF-8  strings, you must build PCRE's 8-bit library with UTF support, and, in addition, you must call  pcre_compile()  with the  PCRE_UTF8 option flag, or the pattern must start with the sequence (*UTF8) or (*UTF). When either of these is the case, both  the  pattern and  any  subject  strings  that  are matched against it are treated as
>   UTF-8 strings instead of strings of individual 1-byte characters.

So the PCRE engine was still seeing `°` as two separate characters, and only making the second half optional.

Note: Interestingly, I was able to get the expected results only using the (lowercase) `u` modifer on my install. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php.

Note 2: My original comment had two options, don't use the other one as it breaks the test that currently works for you.

Comment: `/u` should be what I always use. Thanks.